# which graphics card to use multiple monitors with multiple workspace

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, workspaces

Currently I use core i5 system 2320 @ 3.0GHz with x86-64 bit architecture using Ubuntu 12.04. I intend to buy a Graphics Card which supports to work on multiple monitors for multiple workspaces. Any suggestions which graphics card to buy and how to configure my system for this? I have already installed Compiz on my system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try some 3D software with your xinerama setup ?

[from Xinerama article on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xinerama) :

> In some[which?] implementations, OpenGL (3D) direct-rendering only
>   works on one of the screens. Windows that should show 3D graphics on
>   other screens tend to just appear black. This is most commonly seen
>   with 3D screen savers, which show on one of the screens and black on
>   the others. The Solaris SPARC OpenGL implementation, ATI Proprietary
>   Linux driver and nVidia Proprietary Linux driver all support hardware
>   accelerated rendering to all screens in Xinerama mode.

Comment: No I haven't tried to install any 3d software, is there any way to make changes in the system to achieve this without installing any external software?  Thanks Aurelien

Comment: in the mesa-utils package you have tiny 3D demos, like glxgears. You can try "glxgears -info" to display openGL info. Its a really small package, it may already be installed due to dependencies. Then it should display gears on at least one of you xinerama screen.

Comment: Can You intensify your point based on the question, please?

Comment: @Srijan I'm not sure to understand your comment

Comment: As of now I don't have neither multiple monitors or a graphics card installed on my system, going to buy it in a day or two. So just wanted to make sure that I can setup my environment so as to work as desired. I checked the Xinerama which worked fine with my office system. glxgears -info just works fine. I just want to allocate different workspaces for each monitor.

Comment: So with up-to-date graphic adaptor i think you will not have any problem. Pay attention of you choice between Nvidia/ATI, their drivers has not the same compatibility level with Linux. AFAIK, Nvidia is "better".

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3915/discussion-between-srijan-and-aurelien)